# Loading symbolic variables from Matlab in Python

Tags: python, matlab, numpy, sympy, symbolic-math

I know `spio.loadmat` does not properly load symbolic variables created in Matlab into Python. But, I am wondering if anyone here has ever tried to load such `.mat` files in Python using any sort of trick.

Comment: Such a load would require recreating in sympy variables and expressions that mimic the MATLAB ones. Do you have any idea how similar they are? Maybe you  need to give a MATLAB sample, and the sympy equivalent.

Comment: I personally have no idea how these modules interact with computer. But, it seems to me Matlab does a more rigorous definition for symbols far different from its numeric variables: doubles, chars, ... whereas in Python a symbol looks like a label attached to numeric variable. That's probably why defining a symbol in Matlab take more process time.

Comment: MATLAB `syms` is similar in purpose to `sympy` `symbols()`.

Comment: The thing with scipy's `savemat` and `loadmat` is that they're designed for `.mat` files produced by old MATLAB versions (see note at the end of [this](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.io.loadmat.html) doc page). Nowadays it's probably better to read `.mat` files using an HDF5 tool like `h5py`.